# Is there any way that I can do further calculations using another calculated column alias name in SQL?

Tags: sql

My Original:

```
SELECT 
    100 AS Price, 0.07 AS TaxRate, 
    100 * 0.07 AS TaxAmount, 
    100 + (100 * 0.07) AS Total
```

Can I write it this way? How do I do that?

```
SELECT 
    100 AS Price, 0.07 AS TaxRate, 
    Price * TaxRate AS TaxAmount, 
    Price + TaxAmount AS Total.
```

OR another example...

My original:

```
SELECT 
    ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent,
    ListPrice * (DiscountPercent/100) AS DiscountAmount, 
    ListPrice - (ListPrice * (DiscountPercent/100)) AS DiscountPrice
FROM
    Products
ORDER BY 
    DiscountPrice DESC
```

Desired:

```
SELECT 
    ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent, 
    ListPrice * (DiscountPercent/100) AS DiscountAmount, 
    ListPrice - DiscountAmount AS Discount Price
FROM
    Products
ORDER BY 
    DiscountPrice DESC
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: You need a sub-query or cross-apply to reuse the result of a computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common table expression (CTE) can do this.

```sql
WITH Detail AS (
  SELECT 100 AS Price, 0.07 AS TaxRate
)
SELECT Price, TaxRate, 
       Price * TaxRate AS TaxAmount, 
       Price * (1.0 + TaxRate) AS Total
  FROM Detail
```

If your database doesn't do CTEs, use a subquery.

```sql
SELECT Price, TaxRate, 
       Price * TaxRate AS TaxAmount, 
       Price * (1.0 + TaxRate) AS Total
  FROM (
      SELECT 100 AS Price, 0.07 AS TaxRate
  ) Detail
```

Each level of query can be thought of as a virtual table, with columns that you can name as necessary. So you can use the names of a subquery (or CTE) in an outer query.